# loading data using TensorFlow Datasets and splitting

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

e trouble trying to lead data from tensor flow and i am not able to split the data.

Load the dataset binary_alpha_digits from tensorflow_datasets. Split the dataset into 60% for training and 40% for testing.

I have tried:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
port tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('BinaryAlphaDigits', split=['train', 'test[:40%]'])
```

and i am getting the error
ValueError: Unknown split 'test'. Should be one of ['train'].

appreciate anyone who can help on this thanks

Answer (score 1):

This dataset does not have a `test` split. You can use slicing to split `train` set into:

```
train_ds, test_ds = tfds.load('BinaryAlphaDigits', 
                              split=['train[:60%]', 'train[60%:]'])
```

60% of the dataset will in `train_ds`, rest is in `test_ds`.